# Join DataFrame based on different values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames:

DF 1:

[image]

DF 2:

[image]

I want to join them to have this final DataFrame:

[image]

I have tried many different JOINs or MERGE but any of them are working.

Can anyone help me to get this please??

Thanks in advance!

I have tried left join and merge

Comment: joining on which columns?

Comment: So, the country is the only column in common for all rows in DF1 and DF2 but as you can see, there are some missing values for merchant, payment type,method, issuer on DF2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('Country'), on='Country')
```

or you could merge the sub-DataFrame (with just those columns):

```
df2[list('min_transaction_threshold approval_drop_threshold')]  # df2 but only with columns min_transaction_threshold approval_drop_threshold

df1.merge(df2[list('min_transaction_threshold approval_drop_threshold')])
```

Comment: it will not produce the expected output

Comment: yeah this did not worked, as you can see is required to to join on country where the merchant, payment type, method and issuer are empty, but for the fields that are NOT empty, I can use them for join
its kinda hard to explain, its more easier to look at the deisire result